# How to disable a link in yii2 to access the controller

Tags: yii2

i want disable a link in yii2 ,  i have tried code like this

```
<?= Html::a('Send To', ['/send/now'], [
 'class' => 'btn btn-info',
 'id'=>'now',
 'disabled'=>'disabled',
 'data' => [
    'method' => 'post',
],
]);?>
```

I got the button indication that the button is disabled, but i still can click the button and access the controller.
How to disable the click to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
<?= Html::a('Send To', ['/send/now'], [
 'class' => 'btn btn-info disabled',
 'id'=>'now',
 'data' => [
    'method' => 'post',
],
]) ?>
```

Here is the official Bootstrap guide for [Anchor element](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#anchor-element-1)

For button you can use:

```
<?= Html::button('Send To', [
     'class' => 'btn btn-info',
     'id'=>'now',
     'disabled' => 'disabled'
    ]) ?>
```

Here is the button attributes set for [Button element](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#button-element-1)